# setState with variable react es6

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new here in reactjs, i'm using react-bootstrap for my UI. Now, I encounter a script where in a setState is the value of a variable and pass it on the onHide of the modal. Im not sure what to search to find an answer that's why I posted a question here.

```
let closeBoardAddModal = () => this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: false })
<BoardAddModal show={this.state.boardAddModalShow} onHide={closeBoardAddModal} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let closeBoardAddModal = () => this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: false })
```

In the above stament `closeBoardModal` is not a value but is a `function`. This the ES6 syntax where `()` will contain the arguments and anything after `=>` will be the body of the function. This syntax also the binding operation for you.

The above syntax is equivalent to

```
closeBoardAddModal() {
    this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: false });
}.bind(this);
```

So in the below code

```
<BoardAddModal show={this.state.boardAddModalShow} onHide={closeBoardAddModal} />
```

when you do `onHide={closeBoardAddModal}` it will call  the `function closeBoardAddModal` on an `onHide` event which internally the sets the state `boardAddModalShow` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks Man! I really appreciate your answer.